# Find all files with wildcard or partial pattern

Tags: vb.net, file, filesystems

I have a list of files that i collected into a string(), i want to look inside that list and if i find a match using any wildcard pattern, increment a counter. I'm not sure how to achieve that. Here's what i got so far:

```
Dim mytotal As Integer = 0
Dim lookFor as String = "IWantThisFile"

Dim myList As ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)
myList = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\myfolder\")
Dim filename As String

For Each File As String In myList 
    filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File)

    If lookFor Like filename Then
        mytotal = mytotal Like + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: `mytotal = mytotal Like +1` ?? Apart from that what's wrong with this code?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "lookFor" = "IWantThisFile", my "filename" = IWantThisFileAndMore" therefore does not get increment, how can i get it so that if theres sorta match, increment it.

Comment: `Dim lookFor as String = "IWantThisFile*"` should do it, but maybe you'll have to you reverse: `If lookFor Like filename` => `If filename Like lookFor ` (not sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 problems here:

- `lookFor` is not a pattern. Well it is, but it would only match itself
- `If lookFor Like filename` won't cut it. MSDN states that pattern must be on the right of `Like` operator. It's just the reverse way.
- stray `Like` in `mytotal = mytotal Like + 1`

Posting the fixed code.

```
Dim mytotal As Integer = 0
Dim lookFor as String = "IWantThisFile*"
Dim myList As ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)
myList = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\myfolder\")
Dim filename As String

For Each File As String In myList 
    filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File)

    If filename Like lookFor Then
        mytotal = mytotal + 1
    End If
Next
```